Add-Remove a number from input field when choosing true or false in Angular
I'm trying to add a value of 100 when it's set to true and 0 when it's set to false.
It is currently able to add Rs 100 when set to true but it doesn't revert to 0 when I set it back to false. Where am I doing wrong?
Here's the HTML:
<label>Add Rs 100</label>
<select class="form-select" name="casualty" id="casualty" [(ngModel)]="opd.casualty" (ngModelChange)="addBillingOtherCharges($event)">
  <option value="false">No</option>
  <option value="true">Yes</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="totalAmt" id="totalAmt" [(ngModel)]="billingItem.totalAmount" (ngModelChange)="totalAmountEdited()">

Here's the TS file
addBillingOtherCharges(e:Event){
    if(e){
      this.billingItem.otherAmountKey = "Casualty";
      this.billingItem.otherAmountValue = 100
    }else{
      this.billingItem.otherAmountKey = "";
      this.billingItem.otherAmountValue = 0
    }
    this.calculateTotalAmount()
  }

calculateTotalAmount(){
    this.billingItem.totalAmount = 0
    this.billingItem.totalAmount = (this.billingItem.otherAmountValue==undefined?0:this.billingItem.otherAmountValue)+(this.billingItem.amount||0) - (this.billingItem.discountAmount||0) || 0
  }
totalAmountEdited(){
    this.billingItem.amount = 0;
    this.opd.casualty = false;
    this.billingItem.discountAmount = 0;
  }


Try property binding with ngValue instead of the property value, so it will be [ngValue].
In the old method value will store a string 'true'. Because attributes in html are always taken as string.
In the new method [ngValue] will store a boolean true
The string 'false' will evaluate to true in a if condition.
<label>Add Rs 100</label>
<select class="form-select" name="casualty" id="casualty" [(ngModel)]="opd.casualty" (ngModelChange)="addBillingOtherCharges($event)">
  <option [ngValue]="false">No</option>
  <option [ngValue]="true">Yes</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="totalAmt" id="totalAmt" [(ngModel)]="billingItem.totalAmount" (ngModelChange)="totalAmountEdited()">

Stackblitz Demo

Thank You but adding [value] doesn't change anything. It remains as-is. btw, I forgot to mention that even if I select No (False), it adds 100.

I didn't see any changes. Could you please recheck? Also, I added <option [value]="false">No</option> but the output remains the same.

@ElaineByene please check the ngValue and the working stackblitz

My good lord!! Thank you so much. I have been trying to fix this the entire day.

The easy way: accept that it's a string, and instead of
    if(e) { // do stuff

do
    if(e === 'true') { // do stuff

The neater, more reusable way (if you need it at all) would be to write a custom form control, which would have the model as boolean, instead of string. Because by default input's model is string.
(Here's the official recipe for creating custom form controls:)
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/
